# Facebook Graph Explorer - Why can't I see the call_to_action_type, body, link_url, url_tags, title, and other fields?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am new to programming/API and am watching some tutorials on using the Facebook Marketing API.

I just followed a tutorial to start retrieving data for a creative, but I can't understand why it is not working.

I have the following in the Graph Explorer:
<CREATIVE_ID>?fields=name,status,call_to_action_type,link_url,url_tags,body,title,object_story_spec

But I can only see the name, status, and a few things from the object_story_spec.

Why can't I see all the other data? The body, title, link_url, etc.

The ad is running normally, and the campaign goal is Lead Ads. I have also tested with a Conversion goal campaign.

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4acAM.png)

I have tried to read the official documentation and searched in forums/communities, but still can't understand.